# How I can display message box when no result found in MS Access DB?

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

How can I display a message box when no results are found in MS Access DB using C#?

I'm using this code for Search:

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string query = "SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE emp_ID LIKE '" + textBox5.Text + "'";
command.CommandText = query;
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    slip.Text = reader["emp_ID"].ToString(); 
}
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`HasRows` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Gets a value that indicates whether the OleDbDataReader **contains one
>   or more rows**.

```
if(reader.HasRows)
{

}
else
{
   // Show your message box here
}
```

Also you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbDataReader` automatically instead of calling `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` methods manually.

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
   command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE emp_ID LIKE ?";
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "%" + textBox5.Text + "%");

   using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
       if(reader.HasRows)
       {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
                slip.Text = reader["emp_ID"].ToString(); 
           }
       }
       else
       {
            // Show your message box here
       }
   }
}
```